# Add product with attributes (color, size) in prestashop using web services

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

I am using this sample code to add product in prestashop but I don't know how to add product attributes like quantity, color, size with this product. I have array of color and size that I want to add with this product if that attribute is not added first add these attributes then link with this product.

```
<?php
define('DEBUG', false);
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', false);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/prestashop_demo');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '2LM2T4H56352K1L4FZ40V9H6UPPQD4WE');
require_once ('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
//include_once ('core_config.php');


$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

function PS_new_product($n_id_category_default, $n_id_category, $n_price, $n_active,$n_avail4order,$n_show_price, $n_id_stock_availables ,$n_id_id_product_attribute, $n_l_id, $n_name, $n_desc, $n_desc_short, $n_link_rewrite, $n_meta_title, $n_meta_description, $n_meta_keywords,$n_available_now,$n_available_later) {

    global $webService;

    $xml = $webService -> get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/products?schema=blank'));
    $resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
    unset($resources -> id);
    unset($resources -> position);
    unset($resources -> id_shop_default);
    unset($resources -> date_add);
    unset($resources -> date_upd);

    unset($resources->associations->combinations);
    unset($resources->associations->product_options_values);
    unset($resources->associations->product_features);
    unset($resources->associations->stock_availables->stock_available->id_product_attribute);

    //unset($resources->associations->categories->category->id);

    //unset($resources-> id_category_default);

    //$resources->position_in_category = '0';
    //unset($resources->position_in_category);

    //$resources -> position = '0';
    //$resources -> id;
    $resources-> id_manufacturer = '1';
    $resources-> id_supplier = '1';
    $resources-> id_category_default = $n_id_category_default;
    $resources-> new = '0'; ; //condition, new is also a php keyword!!
    $resources-> cache_default_attribute;
    $resources-> id_default_image;
    $resources-> id_default_combination = '0';
    $resources-> id_tax_rules_group ='1';
    //$resources-> id_shop_default;
    //$resources-> quantity = '50';
    $resources-> reference;
    $resources-> supplier_reference;
    $resources-> location;
    $resources-> width;
    $resources-> height;
    $resources-> depth;
    $resources-> weight;
    $resources-> quantity_discount;
    $resources-> ean13;
    $resources-> upc;
    $resources-> cache_is_pack;
    $resources-> cache_has_attachments;
    $resources-> is_virtual;
    $resources-> on_sale;
    $resources-> online_only;
    $resources-> ecotax;
    $resources-> minimal_quantity = 10;
    $resources-> price = $n_price;
    $resources-> wholesale_price;
    $resources-> unity;
    $resources-> unit_price_ratio;
    $resources-> additional_shipping_cost;
    $resources-> customizable;
    $resources-> text_fields;
    $resources-> uploadable_files;
    $resources-> active = $n_active;
    $resources-> available_for_order = $n_avail4order;
    $resources-> available_date;
    $resources-> condition;
    $resources-> show_price = $n_show_price;
    $resources-> indexed = '1';
    $resources-> visibility = 'both';
    $resources-> advanced_stock_management='0';
    $resources-> date_add;
    $resources-> date_upd;

    $resources->associations->categories->addChild('category')->addChild('id', $n_id_category);

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> name -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_name));
    $resources -> name -> language[0][0] = $n_name;
    $resources -> name -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> name -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> description -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_desc));
    $resources -> description -> language[0][0] = $n_desc;
    $resources -> description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_desc_short));
    $resources -> description_short -> language[0][0] = $n_desc_short;
    $resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_link_rewrite));
    $resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0] = $n_link_rewrite;
    $resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_title));
    $resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_title;
    $resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_description));
    $resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_description;
    $resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_keywords));
    $resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_keywords;
    $resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_available_now));
    $resources -> available_now -> language[0][0] = $n_available_now;
    $resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    $node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]);
    $no = $node -> ownerDocument;
    $node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_available_later));
    $resources -> available_later -> language[0][0] = $n_available_later;
    $resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
    $resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

    try {
        $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
        $xml = $webService -> add($opt);
    } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
        echo '<b>Error : '.$ex->getMessage().'</b>';
        $trace = $ex->getTrace();

        print_r($trace);
    // my log function
    }
}

// simple use

$n_name = 'New product name 5';
$n_desc = 'New product description LONG';
$n_desc_short = 'New product description SHORT';
$n_link_rewrite = 'someone_rewrite_5';
$n_meta_title = 'meta-title';
$n_meta_description = 'meta desc';
$n_meta_keywords = 'some,one,keywords';
$n_available_now = 'Available for order';
$n_available_later = 'Available from gg/mm/yy';

$n_id_category_default = '2';
$n_id_category = '2';
$n_price = '144.65';
$n_active = '1';
$n_avail4order = '1';
$n_show_price ='1';

$n_l_id = '1';

$n_id_stock_availables = '22';
$n_id_id_product_attribute = '0';


// run
PS_new_product($n_id_category_default, $n_id_category, $n_price, $n_active,$n_avail4order,$n_show_price, $n_id_stock_availables ,$n_id_id_product_attribute, $n_l_id, $n_name, $n_desc, $n_desc_short, $n_link_rewrite, $n_meta_title, $n_meta_description, $n_meta_keywords,$n_available_now,$n_available_later);
```

Comment: have you solved this question? How do you add product with attributes and stocks in Prestashop?

Comment: Have you found  a solution for this? I'm stuck in this step, Please if you have solved share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely the linked data approach. You need this to create the resources Colours and Size into Prestashop with or without the service web API. Only after that you could refer to them in to code to create a product with the webservice API.